# How to get the value from the byte array object using ICorProfilerInfo2

Tags: clr-profiling-api

I'm using ICorProfilerCallback2 interface to profiler my application. On function enter hook I'm trying to read the value from byte array which is passed as an argument to a function. I've the argument info COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO from which I can get the starting address of the byte array argument.

If it is a string argument I can use "GetStringLayout" method from ICorProfilerInfo2 interface to get the bufferoffset and stringlengthoffset.

How can I find the offsets for byte array and how to read the values from it?

Where can I find the documents for those?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ObjectID (or COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_RANGE) of the argument, you have an easy life (at least for Objects/Arrays, not for Value Types. You have to validate the parameter type using the metadata).

You can use ICorProfilerInfo::GetClassFromObject and ICorProfilerInfo::IsArrayClass to determine if it's an array. If so, IsArrayClass  gives you the type of array. Arrays in .Net have a specific layout (I don't think it's in the official docs): It's always 8 bytes for ClassID, 8 bytes for size, and than all the elements, without padding (Note: Objects are stored by ObjectID, just like in other memory regions).
You can also use ICorProfilerInfo2::GetArrayObjectInfo to get the size (need to calculate from dimensions) and the starting address of the objects.

Relevant reads:
https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/08/Arrays-and-the-CLR-a-Very-Special-Relationship/
https://windowsdebugging.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/memorylayoutofarraysx64/